# Create table without checking foreign key on unexisting table

Tags: foreign-keys, azure-sql-database, create-table

I'm adapting a really big query (MySQL to SQL) that creates lots of tables and relationships. The problem is that it always check if a table exists prior to adding a foreign key referencing to that table.

So I have to reorder the queries to avoid this problem, and my question is if there's a instruction that can turn that check off, so it'll create the tables and add references without stopping the query with every error it encounters.

I'm working with SQL in an Azure DB.

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Easiest way is to create all tables first and then add constraints using `ALTER TABLE`.

For example:

```
CREATE TABLE a(id INT PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY(1,1), b_id INT, c CHAR(10));
CREATE TABLE b(id INT PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY(1,1), z INT);

ALTER TABLE a ADD CONSTRAINT FK_a_b_id_b FOREIGN KEY (b_id) REFERENCES b(id);
```

**[Rextester Demo](http://rextester.com/HCV7739)**

Comment: Thank you! Anyway I'll have to go through all the queries and change them. Was wondering if isn't a set foreign_check off for the database.

Comment: You don't have to change anything. What tool do you use to script tables? If SSMS there is option to do it automatically.

Comment: Yes I'm using SSMS, but I already got the script, I'm just adapting from MySQL syntax. Problem is that it has 7k rows of script.

Comment: You should really try to use some tool, like MySQL Workbench to script tables